# Agregar campos XML a una pagina web en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, selenium

he estado buscando pero no he encontrado nada que me sea de utilidad, así que he decidido pedir ayuda. Tengo unos campos en *XML* y quiero hacer que con un programa de `python` los añada directamente a una página web, es decir quiero que automáticamente se añadan *1 a 1*, me explico mejor, cuando se active el comando quiero que se añada 1º el nombre, 2º los apellidos, 3º el zip, pero no encuentro la manera de hacer que seleccione solo 1 nombre ( apellidos o zip ) y lo pegue y tampoco logro conseguir que cuando ponga uno no lo vuelva a poner y continúe con el siguiente:

```
<Campos>
    <Persona>
        <Nombre>
            Juan
        </Nombre>
        <Apellidos>
            Perez Diaz
        </Apellidos>
        <zip>
            41006
        </zip>
    </Persona>
    <Persona>
        <Nombre>
            Miguel
        </Nombre>
        <Apellidos>
            Hernandez Collado
        </Apellidos>
        <zip>
            41006
        </zip>
    </Persona>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si tu problema es iterar sobre el xml y obtener los datos de cada persona, puedes usar el módulo `xml.etree` de la stdlib y un generador:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET


def personas_iter(xml):
    campos = ET.parse(xml_file).getroot()
    for persona in campos:
        yield {item.tag: item.text.strip() for item in persona}
```

Ahora puedes iterar sobre el mismo con un ciclo:

```
for persona in personas_iter(xml_file):
    print(persona)
```

> ```
> {'Nombre': 'Juan', 'Apellidos': 'Perez Diaz', 'zip': '41006'}
> {'Nombre': 'Miguel', 'Apellidos': 'Hernandez Collado', 'zip': '41006'}
> ```

o usar `next`:

```
personas = personas_iter(xml_file)

try:
    persona = next(personas)
except StopIteration:
    persona = None
print(persona)
```

> ```
> {'Nombre': 'Juan', 'Apellidos': 'Perez Diaz', 'zip': '41006'}
> ```

```
try:
    persona = next(personas)
except StopIteration:
    persona = None
print(persona)
```

> ```
> {'Nombre': 'Miguel', 'Apellidos': 'Hernandez Collado', 'zip': '41006'}
> ```

```
try:
    persona = next(personas)
except StopIteration:
    persona = None
print(persona)
```

> ```
> None
> ```

Cada item es un diccionario del cual puedes obtener los datos mediante la clave:

```
nombre, apellidos, zip_ = persona["Nombre"], persona["Apellidos"], persona["zip"]
```

y usarlos dónde precises.

Comment: No lo entendí muy bien pero gracias, y cuando pongo este tramo de código me da error:

    `personas = personas_iter(xml_file):
                                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Por cierto, si quiero ponerlo en un label con selenium seria tal que así?:
`driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("(url)")
Nombre = driver.find_element_by_id("Nombre").send_Keys(nombre)
Apellido = driver.find_element_by_id("Apellido").send_Keys(apellido)
zip = driver.find_element_by_id("zip").send_Keys(zip)`

Comment: El error de sintaxis se debe a un error mio al copiar el código, corregido. En cuanto a como usarlo, si, estás en lo correcto. Solo ten cuidado (si usas next y no un for) con intentar obtener elemntos del generador cuando no existen más items (personas disponibles)

Comment: Okay muchisimas gracias, P.D si Sevilla es tu apellido tenemos el mismo xd

Comment: ahora me sale este error `NameError: name 'xml_file' is not defined`

Comment: Si, es mi apellido XD. xml_file debes substituirlo por la ruta a tu archivo xml.

Comment: aaaa vale vale muchas gracias y menuda casualidad, vives en Sevilla y lo flipo xd

Comment: Tengo otro problema, en vez de darme el de Miguel me da otra vez el de Juan:`{'Nombre': 'Juan', 'Apellidos': 'Perez Diaz', 'zip': '41006'}
{'Nombre': 'Juan', 'Apellidos': 'Perez Diaz', 'zip': '41006'}`

Comment: Ten en cuenta que `personas = personas_iter(xml_file)` solo lo debes hacer una vez, esto instancia el generador. Luego usa personas en sucesivas llamadas a next para que en cada una se retornen los datos de la siguiente persona.

Comment: esto es lo que tengo yo puesto de código: `from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

def personas_iter(xml):
    campos = ET.parse("cc.xml").getroot()
    for persona in campos:
        yield {item.tag: item.text.strip() for item in persona}

for i in range(2):
    personas = personas_iter("cc.xml")
    try:
        persona = next(personas)
    except StopIteration:
        persona = None
    print(persona)`

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105494/discussion-between-fjsevilla-and-meganano202).

Comment: Mira el chat por favor